# Encoding in erb templates

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, erb

I created a file:

```
<%
greeting = 'привет'.force_encoding('utf-8')

%>

blah-blah-blah <%= greeting %>
```

and saved it in UTF-8. Then I render it with `erb test.html`. It's ok.

But when I change non-ruby code chars like this:

```
<%
greeting = 'привет'.force_encoding('utf-8')

%>

бла-бла-бла. <%= greeting %>
```

erb throws an error:

```
test.html:6:in `concat': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

Why? If I delete method `force_encoding`, it's ok. It does not make sense to me because I saved the file in UTF-8.

I am using ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14].

Comment: Seems like ERB gets the encoding wrong. Try to insert `<%#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-%>` as the first line in your template. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/erb.rb#L64-L80

Comment: @Stefan, looks like you're right. Instead of adding this line I've used `erb -U` and it's not working. That's strange for me:(. Thank you, anyway. I will try to google more;)